# Firestore: Understanding the read count and pricing applied when searching

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a flutter app and have the following firestore code. There I am searching for the `rooms` where it contains a given `memberid`.

```
return _firestore
          .collection('rooms')
          .where('memberIds', arrayContains: currentUserUid)
          .snapshots()
          .asBroadcastStream();
```

Please consider the following.

1. Assume I have 100 `rooms`.
2. In 20 rooms you can find my `memberId`

Now, if I run the above code once, how many reads will it create and bill me for?

Is it for 1 read, 20 reads or for 100 reads?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore only allows you to execute queries where it can find the documents to return based on the indexes that it keeps. So it doesn't ever have to read each document to determine whether it matches the conditions (something known as a table scan).

So if you return 20 rooms, you will be charged for 20 document reads, no matter how many documents there are in your `rooms` collection.